# How many integers could be in such a way that any digits is not bigger than the left digits?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

How many 4-digits integers could be in such a way that any digits is not bigger than it's left digits?

I Try it with simulation, i get 714. anyone could describe a formula for me?

My try:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe the set you're speaking of? All positive integers? 
How did your code yield 714?

Comment: Dear @daOnlyBG, i edit it.

Comment: Not bigger means it can be equal?

Comment: Dear @Joannes, yes lower or equal.

Comment: Than 'the' left digit or than 'its' left digit?

Comment: I deleted my last comment.  I agree with your 714.

Comment: Dear @John, would u please submit as an answeR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the four digit number to have the digits weakly decreasing (each less than or equal to the digit to the left), I get $715$, so think you missed one.  If I had to guess it is $0000$, but maybe you don't allow that.  One way to think of it is to select four digits allowing repetition.  Each selection generates a single solution-just sort the digits selected in descending order.  One way to get this is  [stars and bars.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) Add 3 to the thousands digit, 2 to the hundreds, 1 to the tens, and 0 to the ones.  Now we don't allow any ties.  Choose 4 numbers from the range 0 through 12 without repetition, which you can do in ${13 \choose 4}=715$ ways.  Sort them, subtract the numbers added, and you have a four digit number with the digits weakly decreasing.

Another approach is to enumerate the distributions of duplicate digits.  No duplicates gives ${10 \choose 4}=210$  One pair gives $10{9 \choose 2}=360$  A triplet gives $90$.  Four of a kind gives $10$.  Two pair gives ${10 \choose 2}=45$  and $210+360+90+10+45=715$

Comment: No, i'm sure : 714.

Comment: I don't understand the logic you are using, but from the pattern it seems you are missing ${3 \choose 3}=1$

Comment: Ross, I went into Excel and ran the test from $1000$ to $9999$, and the result was $714$.  But, the only number less than $1000$ that works is $0000$, so ... +1. :)

Comment: Dear Ross, infact we want to find the 4-digits decreasing numbers. for example 4321.

Comment: Dear @John, you agree with 714?

Comment: But it seems you are including 3321 as well, which is why I said select four digits with repetition.  Otherwise you only get ${10 \choose 4}=210$ of them

Comment: Ross, the 0000 is not 4 digits numbers :) so 714.

Comment: Dear Ross,  can i say comb (13, 4) means select 4 digits from 0 to 12 = 715 - 0000= 714. am i  right?

Comment: I agree with the $714$, yes.  Ross's "stars-and-bars" approach above doesn't exclude $0000$ but that's the only edge case, and it's easily identified.  So you have the answer in closed form, which is $${13 \choose 4} - 1 = 714.$$

Comment: what do u mean by " Add 3 to the thousands digit, 2 to the hundreds, 1 to the tens, and 0 to the ones. Now we don't allow any ties"

Comment: Whether $0000$ was allowed was not clear from the problem statement.  I included it.  My "add 3" etc suggests you consider replacing 7421 with (10)631 and 9999 with (12)(11)(10)9 and so on.  Then any selection of four numbers from [0,12] without repetition corresponds to a number of our form.  It does include $3210 \to 0000$ so you need to delete that one if you like.